# whenever i try to install a library for python using the command prompt in windows, the following error displays on my screen. what do i do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
C:\Users\admin>pip install urllib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 63, in <module>
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list, getproxies, proxy_bypass, proxy_bypass_environment, getproxies_environment
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_http_list' from 'urllib.request' (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py)
```

Comment: Have you named a directory or file `urllib` somewhere in your working directory?

Comment: Oh also, `urllib` is a built-in library... you *can't* install it via `pip` because it already comes with Python.

Answer (score 0):

urllib is an inbuilt library , it cannot be installed via pip

Comment: thanks for answering but then when i run a code using the urllib.request.urlopen("<url>")  it shows error saying urllib.request does not have attribute urlopen.....but this is the exact command i copied from the python documentation as well....so the code is completely correct then why the error.....please answer

Comment: Can you send your code and the error

Comment: `import urllib, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error                                                                      
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen("https://python.org")
for line in fhand :
    print(line.decode().strip())`                   this is the code its not coming with the indentations in the comment but all indentations have been followed

Comment: the error that follows is : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    fhand = urllib.request.urlopen("https://python.org")
AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'urlopen'`

Comment: In my computer your code is running properly

Comment: what must i do now? :(

Comment: Try to make a new Pycharm Project and then use your code there

Comment: tried doing that as well ....i uninstalled all python file and reinstalled the entire setup again ....still no change

Comment: Did you delete Python?

Comment: yeah but reinstalled it again as well